# PHP está lendo a última chave do array

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo .ret do qual me retorna da seguinte maneira:

> 10400000
>   2090183800001990000000000000000000001234204321000000000EMPRESA
>   C ECON FEDERAL                          20601201405551100162204000000 
>   RETORNO-PRODUCAO                  000             10400011T0100030

Coloquei apenas um trecho, pois ele é grande. Para retirar os espaços, fiz dessa forma:

```
$arquivo = file($_FILES["Arquivo"]["tmp_name"]);
$arquivo = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $arquivo);

foreach($arquivo as $linhasNum => $linhas) {
  $testes = substr($arquivo[$linhasNum],63,19);
}
echo $testes;
```

Quando dou um print_r() na variável $arquivo, ele me retorna:

> Array ( [0] =>
>   104000002090183800001990000000000000000000001234204321000000000EMPRESACECONFEDERAL20601201405551100162204000000RETORNO-PRODUCAO000
>   [1] =>
>   10400011T010003020090183800001990000000000000000000001234204321000000000EMPRESA0000162206012014000000000000
>   [2] =>
>   1040001300001T060000000432100000000240000000111369979100000000000000002012014000000000008000000010860000000000000000090000000000000000000000000000125020101

Até a chave [21] que é a última. O problema é que no teste, ele está me retornando apenas essa última chave e não por ordem para eu pegar os valores corretos. Não sei se consegui fazer entender, mas como faço para que o laço percorra todas as chaves por ordem e não pegue somente a última?

Comment: No laço tem que concatenar `$testes .= substr($arquivo[$linhasNum],63,19);`

Comment: Obrigado Leo....

Comment: Mas o problema é o mesmo, Tudo que foi dito aqui é o que eu comentei na anterior. E o pior, você está removendo os espaços com o preg_replace, aí vai desalinhar tudo e atrapalhar seu SUBSTR. Estava melhor o código da anterior.

Comment: Olá Bacco. Na verdade não exatamente a mesma dúvida. A primeira, foi em tentar ler o arquivo da forma como ele vem do banco. Tentei aplicar a solução passada, mas achei melhor retirar os espaços para facilitar o desenvolvimento. Assim foi feito, porém nesse post, o problema é que ao retirar os espaços, estava lendo apenas a última chave e realmente esqueci de colocar o $testes = "" e concatenar dentro do laço $testes .= substr(); para resolver o problema. Achei por bem abrir um novo tópico, pois entendi que são problemas diferenciados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dentro do `foreach()` ele esta definindo a variavel `$teste` a cada loop, então apenas o ultimo valor seria retornado no `echo` após o loop, tenta assim:

```
$arquivo = file($_FILES["Arquivo"]["tmp_name"]);
$arquivo = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $arquivo);
$testes='';
foreach($arquivo as $linhasNum => $linhas) {
  $testes .= substr($arquivo[$linhasNum],63,19);
}
echo $testes;
```